# Is div inside list allowed?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, html-lists

I know that `DIV` inside `LI` isn't allowed, but I've seen it lately on many "big" websites like *Smashing Magazine*, *Web Designer Wall*... etc.

I tried to validate sites, and they have errors, but nothing about `DIV` in `LI`?!

So can I use it inside `LI`, and I need it to be valid?

Comment: Who says `<div>` isn't a valid child element of `<li>`?

Comment: Do you have a specific case you're asking about, or is this a general question? Typically, DIV's are not used inside an LI. Semantically, a DIV has no meaning - it's simply a container for use with presentation concerns. So, it wouldn't really affect the semantics of the document, but the likelihood is that in most cases where you might be tempted to use one, a &lt;SPAN&gt; tag would probably be a better bet.

Comment: The rule is that a `<div>` is not allowed as a direct descendant of `<ul>` or `<ol>`. Because only list items (`<li>`) are allowed in there.

Comment: `<li> can contain any element that is valid in <body>` -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4967976/1066234

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Yes it is valid according to `xhtml1-strict.dtd`. The following XHTML passes the [validation](http://validator.w3.org):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><div>test</div></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is still valid with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`.

Comment: @buildakicker - <!DOCTYPE html> is only used in HTML5 (this declaration is possible because HTML5 is no longer SGML-based, and therefore needs no DTD). It would be incorrect use it in other iterations of the HTML spec where a DTD *is* required.

Comment: @DavidWatson Thanks for the clarification there David. I didn't see a DocType declared in his question up there, but do in this answer.

Comment: If its valid in strict its valid in everything

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa Not entirely. There are several attributes in XHTML 1.0 Strict that are no longer valid in HTML5.

Answer (score 36):

As an addendum: Before HTML 5 while a div inside a li is valid, a div inside a dl, dd, or dt is not!

Comment: Actually, according to the HTML5 draft, the content model of the [`dt`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-dt-element.html#the-dt-element) and [`dd`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-dd-element.html#the-dd-element) elements is "flow content", so a `div` is allowed in both of those. You're right about it not being allowed in `dl` though.

Comment: this was the case in HTML4.. I edited my answer to clarify

Comment: A link confirming this answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Answer (score 15):

If you look at [xhtml1-strict.dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd), you'll see

```
<!ELEMENT li %Flow;>
<!ENTITY % Flow "(#PCDATA | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*">
<!ENTITY % block
     "p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | fieldset | table">
```

Thus `div`, `p` etc. can be inside `li` (according to XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD from w3.org).

Comment: That's true for the HTML 4.01 DTD as well.

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly, a div inside a li **used to** be invalid.

@Flower @Superstringcheese
Div should semantically define a section of a document, but it has already practically lost this role. Span should however contain text.

Comment: the section element is what you want to define a section of a document.  div has no meaning.  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-div-element

Comment: You are talking about a draft, which is not a reality yet.

Comment: If I recall correctly @mystrdat you are correct. Somebody challenged my recent assertion that you could not do this, and when I looked it up I was wrong. But I strongly recall actually validating markup one time where the error output clearly stated I was not allowed to put divs inside lis.

Answer (score 0):

I see you would want to do this if you wanted to make, say, the whole box of a menu item clickable. I used to insert an `<li>` tag in `<a>` tags to do this but this seems more valid.

Comment: If you want to make a "whole box" of a menu item clickable, you simply need to set its child anchor element to "display:block" or "display:inline-block" with CSS. No need to hack the markup for that purpose.