# How to get the value of this nested div

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I need to get the value of the div "code"

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li>
      <div id="img01" style:"background-image: url(…);">
      <div id="name01">Frekad</div> 
      <div id="code01">3234427APW</div>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div id="img02" style:"background-image: url(…);">
      <div id="name02">Rosswa</div>
      <div id="code02">3234423AQW</div>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div id="img03" style:"background-image: url(…);">
      <div id="name03">Jeppo</div>
      <div id="code03">3234425AQQ</div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I need to get the codeXX value for each li  into an array. Thanks.

Comment: divs are not allowed inside a <li>

Comment: @Chuck : Not sure the W3C agree with that... http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://innervisions.org.uk/bar.htm&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654

Comment: Lazarus is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915077/is-div-inside-list-allowed

Comment: Thirded - LI is a block level element which are generally permissive, and the XSDs for html and xhtml both allow DIV (amongst others)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following loop to iterate through all the codeXX divs:

```
$("div[id^='code']").each(function(){
});
```