# What are the allowed tags inside a <li>?

Tags: html, html-lists

I have been searching for the list of tags that are available inside a `<li>`, but I couldn't find any reference.

Is it possible that any standards-compliant HTML 4+ block element is allowed in them?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

**TL;DR**: an `<li>` can contain any element that is valid in `<body>`.

In the [HTML 4.01 spec for lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-UL) you’ll find the relevant extract of the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT LI - O (%flow;)* -- list item -->
```

This specifies that an `<li>` may contain [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#flow), which is the collection of all [block](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#block) and [inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline) elements.

The [HTML5 spec for an `<li>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) is the same in that it also allows any [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1).

Answer (score 9):

It's a block level element so pretty much anything goes. Trouble only comes when you're putting block level elements inside inline ones.

Comment: P-tags are block-level elements, but may not contain any block-level elements.  "Anything goes" is not quite accurate in regards to block-level: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it

Comment: Hence '`pretty much` anything goes'. There's a 171 upvoted answer on this 7 year old question so I think people will be ok

Answer (score 4):

Yup, pretty much. You can have lists inside lists (<strike>either inside the `<li>` or just loose inside the `<ol>`/`<ul>`</strike> *the inner list must be inside an `<li>`*), block elements and inline elements.

To me it wouldn't make much sense to put a `<table>` inside an `<li>`, but even that's still valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [W3C's Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to test against your cases to know whether or not your markup is valid.

> This validator checks the markup
>   validity of Web documents in HTML,
>   XHTML, SMIL, MathML, etc.