# What type of HTML elements can I place inside li tags?

Tags: html, html-lists

What type of elements can I place inside of my li tags? I'm trying to make a list of friends for my website and I want to put in picture and more in each "list item".

What type of tags can I use?

Comment: inside a li tag you can put what you want... are you having any problem?

Comment: You can use pretty much any element that's valid for your `DOCTYPE`. Some caveats would be `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>` (the 'obvious' ones), and there are probably a few more

Comment: Note that all answers given apply to *most* elements and aren't limited to `li`.

Comment: @MCSI: No problems, I want a more solid foundation on what type of tags I can place there instead of just winging it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the allowed tags inside a <li>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li)

Comment: Sorry to be lame, but I think this is an exact duplicate of: ["What are the allowed tags inside a <li>?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4967976/25847), which appeared a few months before your question.

Answer (score 4):

Almost any inline or block level element., In this case this would work well:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src="source.jpg" alt="alt" />
      <p><a href="#">link</a></p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <img src="source.jpg" alt="alt" />
      <p><a href="#">link</a></p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a list item you can put text, line breaks, images, links, other lists, etc.