# Alternative for having a li inside li element in HTML Form

Tags: html, html-lists, forms, xhtml-transitional

I am creating a form where in 'Are you affiliated to institution? Y/N' question should show up another small forms which have the relevant information. 
I am trying to have the jQuery `fadeIn()` `fadeOut()` methods & trying to show the subform. but when I try to do it.

1. putting an `li` tag to whole form & trying to call. But it says I cannot put `li` inside another `li` in XHTML 1.0 Transitional
2. When I try to put the subform inside the `div` then it says `div` cannot be placed inside `ul` element.

Is there a way to work around this? I am thinking changing the DOCTYPE would do but I am now sure which one would be good one or may be there is some other way to work around with the tags.

**Part 2 :**

I succesfully got to work my subform fading thing working. But When I press Y in first instance & then select N option. The two subforms get concatenated. I think I have to write more of the javascript to make it a mutual exclusive event. Here is my js

```
   <script type="text/javascript" >
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#subafform').hide();
      $("#element_4_1").click( function(){
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
               $('#subafform').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#subafform').fadeOut();
        }
        });
        });

    </script>
```

Similarly for NO option my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#subnonafform').hide();
 $("#element_4_2").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
           $('#subnonafform').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#subnonafform').fadeOut();
    }
    });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is it feasible for your layout to nest a ul into a li and fade IN/OUT that one.

Comment: You're doing it wrong: `<ul><li>Item<ul><li>Sub Item</li></ul></li></ul>`. i recommend [reading the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-li-element.html#the-li-element).

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What are the allowed tags inside a <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot put an li in an li, but you can put it in a ul

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is that also the case in HTML5?

Answer (score 2):

<li> cannot have direct <li> children. Make sure whatever you have written is not trying to make that happen.

Similarly, <div> cannot be a direct child of <ul>. But it can be a direct child of <li> inside <ul>.