# error code with html jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error changing html content with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311787/error-changing-html-content-with-jquery)

What is wrong here? I want replace ul content with other content.

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
   $('#foo2').html('<li><div id="lines"></div><div id="tittle">2 PROGRAMEO, LONDRES</div><div id="image"></div><div id="text">LOREM IPSUM XHTML+CSS3 HTTP://WWW.url.com/</div></li>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Txyse/

My solution so far is:

```
$('#foo2').load("content1.html");
```

Another solution?

Comment: Are some of those ids already used.  You can only have one of each id on a page.

Comment: div should not be nested in li. You should create a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @namkha87 `div`s in `li`s are fine, you just have to have your `li`s as the direct children of your `ul`

Comment: Seems to work.  Did you get an error in the console?

Comment: Your question is somehow like: *"my code works but it doesn't work, please help"* http://jsbin.com/ituguq/1/edit

Comment: Off topic but for those who think that we can't have nested `div` in `li` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li

Comment: For one thing, your fiddle is pointing to Mooytools 1.4.5 while your question is referencing jQuery. You also have some illegal carriage returns which will break your JS. [Here is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Txyse/12/) which appears to be working just fine. I can't really add this as an answer since your formatting above is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery framework from left panel of the fiddle then try this code:

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
    $('#foo2').html("<li><div id='lines'></div><div id='tittle'>TITTLE2</div><div id='image'></div><div id='text'>TEXT2</div></li>");
});
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance and a lot of thanks for your answer. Finally i will use .load.