# Error changing html content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is wrong here? I want replace ul content with other content

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
$('#foo2').html('<li><div id="lines"></div><div id="tittle">2 PROGRAMEO, LONDRES</div><div id="image"></div><div id="text">LOREM IPSUM XHTML+CSS3 HTTP://WWW.url.com/</div></li>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Txyse/

Comment: possible duplicate of [error code with html jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311603/error-code-with-html-jquery)

Comment: So... why did you ask the same question twice within one hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fiddle includes mootools instead of jQuery.

You have a line break in a string in your fiddle. Either remove it or add a `\` at the end of the first line of the string like below: (notice the `\` at the end of the 2nd line of code below)

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
  $('#foo2').html('<li><div id="lines"></div>\
                  <div id="tittle">TITTLE2</div><div id="image"></div><div id="text">TEXT2</div></li>');
                  });
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Txyse/3/)

Comment: thanks!!!! Work fine. and yes, sachleen, i'm new here and i must wait a lot of time for write. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
  $('#foo2').html('<li><div id="lines"></div><div id="tittle">TITTLE2</div><div id="image"></div><div id="text">TEXT2</div></li>');
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Txyse/8/

Comment: When answering please make sure to explain what you changed in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your fiddle.

1. jQuery is not loaded
2. Your Javascript has a line break in a string
3. The click event needs to be attached after the document is loaded

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Txyse/2/) works

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#carouselselectitem1').click(function() {
        $('#foo2').html('<li><div id="lines"></div><div id="tittle">TITTLE2</div><div id="image"></div><div id="text">TEXT2</div></li>');
  });
});
```

Comment: @sachleen - true, but it is also not uncommon for beginners to miss point 3 and we have no knowledge of the rest of the OP's code.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally deleted my comment. For @PassKit's reply to make any sense I had said jsFiddle takes care of #3