# What child elements are valid inside of a <li>?

Tags: html, css

Say I have

```
<li></li>
```

What are the rules when putting other tags inside of these? For instance

```
<li>Hello. <p>I am a paragraph</p></li>
```

or

```
<li>Hello. <span>I am a span</span></li>
```

What should be taken into consideration when doing this?

Comment: You're asking about the difference between a block and inline element.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with either..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li

Answer (score 14):

Both `<p>` & `<span>` are [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), which is [permitted as the child of an `<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li), which means both are equally valid in HTML5.

Answer (score 6):

Any kind of flow element is allowed inside of an `<li>`.

Check out:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#flow-content-0
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content

Answer (score 1):

This depends on HTML version, so consult the specification or draft that you regard as relevant. Generally, the content model of `li` allows any element that is valid in the document body, but the set of such elements depends on HTML version of course.