# Css - yet another tree view open / close and parent question

Tags: css

I'm fighting with this for 2 days and it may be simple, but I'm not getting there.
I want to have a nice, clean tree view with multiple levels and I'm trying to first target children after root. I can do that, but I'm sure using ~ and + signs this may be simpler. Second I need the checkboxes to open / close the tree.
I know I can always use a pre made one, but I want need to learn.
Any help?
No javascript or query, pure css please.

```css
ul.tree li a {
  /* 1º Nível */
  color: red;
}

ul.tree ul>li a {
  /* 2º Nível */
  color: blue;
}

ul.tree ul>ul li a {
  /* 3º Nível */
  color: yellow;
}

ul.tree ul>ul>ul li a {
  /* 4º Nível */
  color: green;
}

ul.tree ul>ul>ul>ul li a {
  /* 5º Nível */
  color: orange;
}

ul.tree>input.[type=checkbox]:checked ul.tree ul>li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li><input type=checkbox /><b>_root</b></li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
  <li>
    <ul class="pasta">
      <li><input type=checkbox /><b>Pasta A</b></li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
      <li>
        <ul class="pasta">
          <li><input type=checkbox /><b>Pasta A - 1</b></li>
          <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
          <li>
            <ul class="pasta">
              <li><input type=checkbox /><b>Pasta dentro da pasta A - 1</b></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li>
                <ul class="pasta">
                  <li><input type=checkbox /><b>Pasta dentro da pasta dentro da pasta A -1</b></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
</ul>
```

the fiddle

[example of what I made](https://jsfiddle.net/a3ef9czh/1/)

Comment: Your html is totally invalid - ul can only have li as direct children so you either need to use divs or javascript

Comment: Thanks Pete, I didn't know that, I'm updating the html, w3c valid now.

Comment: now css doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately now you won't be able to use the sibling selectors on the checkboxes as they are no longer siblings so you will need to use js with that structure

Comment: You haven't adjusted the CSS accordingly, though. `ul.tree>input.[type=checkbox]:checked` should never match an element (as `input` cannot be a direct child of `ul`).

Comment: There is a way to go with a valid HTML implementation and also use the checkbox "hack" for displaying/hiding. That one has to place the checkboxes before the `ul` and in place of the checkboxes in the list, use a label for each of those checkboxes. Now something like `input#root:checked + ul > li > ul { ... }` could work.

Comment: Oh yes. It's possible with perfectly valid HTML markup :) I will write an official answer, but it takes time fo untangle this spaghetti.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, and later I will link to the documentation and explain what I have done. I have validated the HTML. Strange syntax in CSS that you're seeing is [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) methodology. You should avoid targeting bare elements and always try to give them specific class.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nemanjaglumac/tazLkgc9/) - if you find it easier.

**Please note:** Although I have tried to use best practices both for HTML and CSS, this is **NOT** something you would do in production. It is too "hacky" and the "price" for pure css solution is much higher than if we decided to use a little bit of JS. But, nevertheless it was interesting to try and overcame the obstacles, that is - to propose the solution within the boundaries you have set.

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* LIST style hacks which allows us to avoid bullets before checkbox - unfortunately, we have to supply and fake the bullets with pseudo before element for every li where we want them */
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.ficheiro::before {
  content: "•";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
}

.pasta-1 .ficheiro::before {
  content: "°";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 3px;
}

.pasta-2 .ficheiro::before {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 3px;
}

/* CHECKBOX hacks for selectively hiding and showing the parts of the tree */
.tree {
  display: none;
}

#level-0:checked ~ .tree {
  display: block;
}

.pasta-1,
.pasta-2,
.pasta-3,
.pasta-4 {
  display: none;
}

#level-1:checked ~ .pasta-1 {
  display: block;
}

#level-2:checked ~ .pasta-2 {
  display: block;
}

#level-3:checked ~ .pasta-3 {
  display: block;
}

#level-4:checked ~ .pasta-4 {
  display: block;
}

/* LINKS */
.ficheiro {
  position: relative;
}

.ficheiro__link--root {
  color: red;
}

.ficheiro__link--level-1 {
  color: blue;
}

.ficheiro__link--level-2 {
  color: yellow;
}

.ficheiro__link--level-3 {
  color: green;
}

.ficheiro__link--level-4 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input id="level-0" type="checkbox" /> 
<label for="level-0">_root</label>
<ul class="tree">
  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--root" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--root" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
  <li>
    <input id="level-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="level-1">Pasta A</label>
    <ul class="pasta-1">
      <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-1" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-1" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-1" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
      <li>
        <input id="level-2" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="level-2">Pasta A - 1</label>
        <ul class="pasta-2">
          <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-2" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
          <li>
            <input id="level-3" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="level-3">Pasta dentro da pasta A - 1</label>
            <ul class="pasta-3">
              <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-3" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-3" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-3" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li>
                <input id="level-4" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="level-4">Pasta dentro da pasta dentro da pasta A -1</label>
                <ul class="pasta-4">
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-4" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-4" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-4" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-4" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-4" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-3" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
              <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-3" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-2" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--level-1" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--root" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
  <li class="ficheiro"><a class="ficheiro__link--root" href="#">ficheiro</a></li>
</ul>
```

Try to understand what is happening in the code, and why I have structured it the way I have. It's best way to learn. Meanwhile, I will prepare the links and explanations and append them in the later edit.

**EDIT:**

1. You can validate code with [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/). It will scream at you
   because we're missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `lang`, `title`, etc. but
   the code itself is valid.
2. [MDN - li element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li):

   - permitted parents: `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`
   - permitted content: [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) (basically, [any element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968037/8815185) that is valid within `<body>`)
3. [30 CSS selectors you should know](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) - we were using sibling combinator `~` (number 9 on this list of 30)
4. CSS code could be much cleaner with the use of preprocessor such as [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) and [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6), or even with the simple nesting.
5. When you target elements several levels deep, you're increasing the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and make it extremely hard to maintain it later. You can try this [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) to understand it better. That's why one of the best practices is to use classes. With good naming, the code basically documents itself and it's quite clear what your intention was. You immediately know which element belongs to which level just by looking at the class names.

Comment: Thanks, I did never heard about BEM methodology (+plus one for that), this post was so helpful, I'm right now reading the BEM website and just found so many mistakes I usually do. now about the tree, the only problem here is that if we have more sub-levels we need to add more css, but for me its perfect!

Comment: @Pluda Glad to hear that! I have added a lot of new links and explanations which I hope you'll find helpful. Check it out and let me know if I have missed something. And there's also a link to JSFiddle where it might be easier to inspect the code and play with it.