# When working with css child combinator on list i'm not getting the result I expected

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have a list and i'm trying to figure out why **H** is not colored red, when **D E F** are colored. 
Isn't the path for **H** `.pages > li > ul > li` ?

What I noticed is that if I remove **G** or if I change **G**'s tag to anything else, like a `<p>` tag, then **H** is colored red;

```css
.sitemap li {
  color: teal;
}

.pages > li > ul > li {
  color: red
}
```

```html
 <aside class="sitemap">
          <ul class="pages">
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C
              <ul>
                <li>D</li>
                <li class="featured">E</li>
                <li>F</li>
              </ul>
              <li>G</li>
              <ul>
                <li>H
                  <ul>
                    <li class="featured">I</li>
                    <li>J</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
```

Comment: you aren't correctly closing your li elements (check around the G). an li cannot be a child of li

Comment: you are not closing the `li` that contains **C** so the `li` of **G** is invalid.

Comment: I was taking a quiz on ```https://mjswensen.github.io/css-power-ups/the-cascade-and-specificity/specificity-quiz/``` The last question is where i got the code from, So im guessing what is messing it up is that a ```li``` cannot be a child of ```li```

Comment: *The code I provided doesnt have any errors.* --> use validator to see the errors: https://validator.w3.org/ .. taking an existing code doesn't mean it's error free and this one is clearly invalid.

Comment: Duplicate of [What are the allowed tags inside a <li>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967976/what-are-the-allowed-tags-inside-a-li)

Comment: Mate this is a wrong code and why are you not understanding & why you stick to that quiz competition when the format of HTML is in wrong manner and it's not in proper way. The below answers are correct according to your question and try to understand. If you some other query or other problem then change your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot 2 lines in the html. After that, your style will work fine but it will also change the color of D, E and F because they are on the same level as H.

```
<aside class="sitemap">
  <ul class="pages">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C
      <ul>
        <li>D</li>
        <li class="featured">E</li>
        <li>F</li>
      </ul>
    </li> <!-- add this line -->
    <li>G</li>
    <li> <!-- add this line -->
      <ul>
        <li>H
          <ul>
            <li class="featured">I</li>
            <li>J</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: I copied the code from a css quiz, so im not sure if it was intentional for them to place it the way that they did, but I want to know why it works the way it does.

Comment: This answer could benefit from explaining why OP needs the closing tags; I'm certain he didn't "forget" them, but rather "didn't realize they were needed".

Comment: I think it's beyond the css quiz but the answer here is `.pages > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li { color: red; }`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to handle `<ul>` and `<li>` nesting the proper way.

The mistake in your code is you have `<li>G</li>` as a direct descendant of `<li> c`. Having a `<li>` inside another `<li>` is illegal; `<li>` elements may only be placed as children of `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`.

Please see the following code snippet to see a properly-terminated set of list-items.

```css
.sitemap li {
    color: teal;
}
.pages > li > ul > li {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<aside class="sitemap">
    <ul class="pages">
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C
            <ul>
                <li>D</li>
                <li class="featured">E</li>
                <li>F</li>
            </ul>
        </li> <!-- point c <li> is complete here after completing your subpoints of main point c -->
        <li>G
            <ul><!-- now for H is a sub point for G so just move this <ul> inside of the <li> of point G -->
                <li>H
                    <ul>
                        <li class="featured">I</li>
                        <li>J</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: I copied the code from a css quiz, so im not sure if it was intentional for them to place it the way that they did, but I want to know why it works the way it does.

Comment: I clearly say in my answer that <ul> and <li> nesting is not proper that's why this is working like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you write like that.It is a wrong way for unordered list `ul`.List item's `li` parent must be `ul`.By the way, if you want to continue write like that, you can put

```
.pages > ul >li{
  color: red;
}
```