# Drop down layout - how to make "columns"

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, multiple-columns

I've got the standard drop down layout that many people use, nested `<ul>` elements inside of `<li>` elements. Here's the thing: I want to get those child `<li>` elements to show in columns. Assuming I have 20 items, I would like four rows of five elements. I've been doing this by outputting a `<span>` tag around each group of 5 list items, only to foolishly forget that span is not allows as a direct child of an unordered list. E.G

```
<span class="col">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</span>
```

This, visually, works fine but obviously won't validate. I've searched around a lot for solutions to this and I'm seriously stuck. Does anyone know how I can display these list items in columns? I've also read (didn't know) that `<li>` elements may only have `<ul>`, `<ol>` and `<menu>` as parent elements, which isn't much use at the moment. The best I can think of is;

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul><!--drop down with columns-->
            <li><!--column-->
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><!--column-->
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><!--column-->
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><!--column-->
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...which looks very wasteful of HTML. Any ideas..?

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Your example markup actually looks fine to me: it is robust and will work cross-browser. That said, what browsers are you aiming to support? And does the order of your sub-items matter? Finally, do you have a design showing what you're trying to achieve visually?

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez Hi, it does work (top fragment of code), but validation fails because <span> is a direct child of a <li> element. I don't have an example to hand, but basically it's a full width drop down (960px for example), with 4 columns. The links are arranged like this: <span> link 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and then </span>. The pattern then carries on that way to fill the remaining columns.

Comment: The nested `<ul>` HTML you provided looks good, I'd go with that.  It's not wasteful HTML if it's semantically the correct structure.

Comment: Your own html, see demo here - http://jsbin.com/asenEnIH/1/edit

Comment: What are your cross-browser requirements? IE support needed? oldIE?

Comment: @davidpauljunior - thanks for taking the time to do that. That is the only logical markup I can think of but it seems pretty excessive? If nobody has anything more efficient then I'd better go with it.

Comment: @MarkSimpson as broad as possible. Ideally IE7 onwards. The currently solution with the span tags works really well, I just swore when I realised I'm not "allowed" to do it..!

Comment: I don't see why CSS columns is necessary here.  You can create your columns using floats or display: inline-block.  The markup may seem bloated, but that is the correct structure.  Why are you so keen to use less HTML?  It won't be a performance hit or anything.  In fact, I'd probably add an extra title in there for accessibility. Like this:  http://jsbin.com/asenEnIH/2/edit

Comment: Just for html to content ratio alone. I just try to have less crap on the page where possible. In the end I've gone for the extra markup and it's working well so far. Sadly I have to change quite a lot of CSS, but it's got me thinking, maybe I ought to move away from using lists for menus. There's an interesting article on CSS tricks about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IE 9 and older aren't a priority, you can use CSS columns to achieve what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/kXDDL/1/

Browsers that don't support it (IE 6,7,8,9) will still show your menu just fine, except in a straight vertical column (which is the usual way menus are shown so should be fine). Alternatively, you could use a polyfill for non-supporting browsers.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
<ul class="parent-list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Daddy 1
        <ul class="child-list">
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
            <li>Child 5</li>
            <li>Child 6</li>
            <li>Child 7</li>
            <li>Child 8</li>
            <li>Child 9</li>
            <li>Child 10</li>
            <li>Child 11</li>
            <li>Child 12</li>
            <li>Child 13</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

.parent-list > li {
    float: left;
}

.child-list {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
       -moz-column-width: 100px;
}
.child-list > li {
    width: 100px;
}
```

POLYFILLS:
[CSS3MultiColumn](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn)
[Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

REFERENCES:
http://caniuse.com/multicolumn
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

Comment: I do like this solution, but browser support is an issue. For a fallback, I guess I could float all <li> elements left with a 25% width. They won't look the same, but sod that : )

Comment: @Dan I've updated my answer to include polyfills that you can use, if that's your preference.

Comment: Many thanks Mark - I'll check out the polyfills. I think this is the most futureproof example, but in the end (on this job) I've gone for extra ul's and li's to sort out the issue. For future usage I'd like to build your idea into my little menu plugin!

Comment: Cheers Dan. I understand the need to be pragmatic. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

sTry with some css.

add a class to the lines:

```
<li><!--column-->
```

something like:

```
<li class="column"><!--column-->
```

Then you can add somewhere the css rule:

```
.column{
 float:left;
}
```

This should do the trick.

EDIT:
I'm still not sure if i understand the problem but i'll try again :)

```
<div class='column'>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class='column'>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>

.column{
 float:left;
}
```

Is using floated divs less of a waste of html code? (cause to me your nested li's seem perfect).

Comment: Otherwise you can always create a <table> if you need to add a table structure.

Comment: Hi @CosLu, this is pretty easy, the problem is the order of links in the column. I don't want them going "sideways", they need ordering 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in a single column, and then 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in the next column.

Comment: So you just want to achieve the result of your second example with less html code? I edited the answer.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. As long as it's in columns some how.

Comment: I don't think that will work as a div element is also not allowed as a child of an <li> element?

Comment: You can depending on how you declare the page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915077/is-div-inside-list-allowed , but in my example we're not putting any div inside a li. The divs will appear one next to the other without putting them in any list.