# HTML lists not visible

Tags: html, list

I have no clue why my page doesnt display the point i want to be in lists as lists. It just gives out all the points between the li tags in the same line.
also can i link the same css files to all my text files?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>eligiblitypage</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Are You Eligible?</h1>
  <p>It is great that you took the first step. Yes thinking about 
    getting transferred. But before proceeding, checks out if 
    you are eligible for the college you are applying to.</p>
  <div class="first">
     <div class="info">
        <ol>

       <li>The first step would be to:      
              <ol>
        <li>Make a list of colleges which you find to be a good match for you (yes Ivies also take transfers!)</li>
        <li>If you dont know much about colleges in the US, exploring the CollegeBoard website would be
            the first step for you <a href="https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-search?navid=gh-cs">College Search</a></li>
        <li>Filter according to your needs in the website and then finalize some colleges for which you are
            eligible.</li>
          </ol></li>



        <li>Next Steps!
            <ol><li>Now that you have got a list of the colleges, visit the college websites and explore the various
            oppurtunities you may have in that college.</li>        
        <li>Also look throught the transfer requirements to see if the college has some special requirements
            for transfer students</li>
        <li>Attending college in the US may get costly. Try to look at what the cost of attending college would be. If you are an intenrational student
            ,check out the financial aid page and also the scholarships offered if any.</li>
          </ol></li>



        <li>Final Steps
          <ol>
        <li>Dont forget to check on the website if the colleges in your list offer your desired major</li>
        <li>Also check the college coursework and see whether you can handle it or not</li>
        <li>Now that you know about your eligibility, you can move on to the <a href="#">application process imformation<a></li>
          </ol></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>         
   </html>
```

Also can i add div tags in individual li tags?

Comment: One of your anchor tags isn't closed properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the last `<a>` tag, and everything should be fixed.

Change

```
<li>Now that you know about your eligibility, you can move on to the <a href="#">application process imformation<a></li>
```

to

```
<li>Now that you know about your eligibility, you can move on to the <a href="#">application process imformation</a></li>
```

**Edit:**
Here's the complete working body with the one change above, as well as reformatted:

```
<body>
   <h1>Are You Eligible?</h1>
   <p>It is great that you took the first step. Yes thinking about 
      getting transferred. But before proceeding, checks out if 
      you are eligible for the college you are applying to.
   </p>
   <div class="first">
      <div class="info">
         <ol>
            <li>
               The first step would be to:      
               <ol>
                  <li>Make a list of colleges which you find to be a good match for you (yes Ivies also take transfers!)</li>
                  <li>If you dont know much about colleges in the US, exploring the CollegeBoard website would be
                     the first step for you <a href="https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-search?navid=gh-cs">College Search</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>Filter according to your needs in the website and then finalize some colleges for which you are
                     eligible.
                  </li>
               </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
               Next Steps!
               <ol>
                  <li>Now that you have got a list of the colleges, visit the college websites and explore the various
                     oppurtunities you may have in that college.
                  </li>
                  <li>Also look throught the transfer requirements to see if the college has some special requirements
                     for transfer students
                  </li>
                  <li>Attending college in the US may get costly. Try to look at what the cost of attending college would be. If you are an intenrational student
                     ,check out the financial aid page and also the scholarships offered if any.
                  </li>
               </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
               Final Steps
               <ol>
                  <li>Dont forget to check on the website if the colleges in your list offer your desired major</li>
                  <li>Also check the college coursework and see whether you can handle it or not</li>
                  <li>Now that you know about your eligibility, you can move on to the <a href="#">application process imformation</a></li>
               </ol>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Also, you may want to fix the typo of "imformation" to "information" while you're at it.

Comment: I put in the whole body as amended above.  If you copy and paste it over your body, it should work.  If you're still having issues, it may be in your main.css file.

Comment: got it. Seems like the CSS was messing witht the view. Needed some class changing . Thanks

Comment: To answer your other question, you can indeed put `<div>` tags inside of `<li>`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915077/is-div-inside-list-allowed